# Adding external assembler function to C project

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to call assembler procedure which is supposed to calculate CRC32 checksum for file from C app.

C code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>

    extern unsigned long __stdcall CRC32(size_t sizeOfFile, char buffer[]);


    int fsize(char* file) {
        int size;
        FILE* fh;

        fopen_s(&fh, file, "rb" );
        if(fh != NULL){
            if( fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_END) ){
                fclose(fh);
                return -1;
            }

            size = ftell(fh);
            fclose(fh);
            return size;
        }

        return -1; //error
    }

    void calculateChecksum(char * filename, char * checksum){
        FILE *file = NULL;

        unsigned long crc32;


        char hex[10];
        fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb" );
        size_t size = fsize(filename);
        char *buffer=(char*)malloc(size);
        fread_s(buffer,size,size,1,file);
        crc32=CRC32(size,buffer);
        int n = sprintf_s(hex,"%x",crc32);

        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            checksum[i]=hex[i];
        }
        fclose(file);
        file = NULL;
    }




    int main(){
        char checksum[8];
        calculateChecksum("B:\\secretMessageC#.txt",checksum);

        char hex[10];

        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            checksum[i]=hex[i];
            printf("%c",checksum[i]);
        }

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Assember code:

```
    .686 
    .387
    .model flat, stdcall 
    .xmm
    .data
    .code
    CRC32 proc sizeOfFile:DWORD, file:DWORD
        push    esi
        push    ecx
        push    edx

        mov esi, file
        xor edx, edx
        or  eax, -1
        mov ecx, sizeOfFile

    CRC32_loop:
        mov dl, byte ptr [esi]
        xor dl, al
        shr eax, 8
        xor eax, dword ptr [crc32_table + 4*edx]
        inc esi
        dec ecx
        jnz CRC32_loop

        not eax

        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop esi
        ret
            CRC32 endp
    crc32_table dd 000000000h, 077073096h, 0EE0E612Ch, 0990951BAh, 0076DC419h, 0706AF48Fh, 0E963A535h, 09E6495A3h, 00EDB8832h, 079DCB8A4h
                dd 0E0D5E91Eh, 097D2D988h, 009B64C2Bh, 07EB17CBDh, 0E7B82D07h, 090BF1D91h, 01DB71064h, 06AB020F2h, 0F3B97148h, 084BE41DEh
                dd 01ADAD47Dh, 06DDDE4EBh, 0F4D4B551h, 083D385C7h, 0136C9856h, 0646BA8C0h, 0FD62F97Ah, 08A65C9ECh, 014015C4Fh, 063066CD9h
                dd 0FA0F3D63h, 08D080DF5h, 03B6E20C8h, 04C69105Eh, 0D56041E4h, 0A2677172h, 03C03E4D1h, 04B04D447h, 0D20D85FDh, 0A50AB56Bh
                dd 035B5A8FAh, 042B2986Ch, 0DBBBC9D6h, 0ACBCF940h, 032D86CE3h, 045DF5C75h, 0DCD60DCFh, 0ABD13D59h, 026D930ACh, 051DE003Ah
                dd 0C8D75180h, 0BFD06116h, 021B4F4B5h, 056B3C423h, 0CFBA9599h, 0B8BDA50Fh, 02802B89Eh, 05F058808h, 0C60CD9B2h, 0B10BE924h
                dd 02F6F7C87h, 058684C11h, 0C1611DABh, 0B6662D3Dh, 076DC4190h, 001DB7106h, 098D220BCh, 0EFD5102Ah, 071B18589h, 006B6B51Fh
                dd 09FBFE4A5h, 0E8B8D433h, 07807C9A2h, 00F00F934h, 09609A88Eh, 0E10E9818h, 07F6A0DBBh, 0086D3D2Dh, 091646C97h, 0E6635C01h
                dd 06B6B51F4h, 01C6C6162h, 0856530D8h, 0F262004Eh, 06C0695EDh, 01B01A57Bh, 08208F4C1h, 0F50FC457h, 065B0D9C6h, 012B7E950h
                dd 08BBEB8EAh, 0FCB9887Ch, 062DD1DDFh, 015DA2D49h, 08CD37CF3h, 0FBD44C65h, 04DB26158h, 03AB551CEh, 0A3BC0074h, 0D4BB30E2h
                dd 04ADFA541h, 03DD895D7h, 0A4D1C46Dh, 0D3D6F4FBh, 04369E96Ah, 0346ED9FCh, 0AD678846h, 0DA60B8D0h, 044042D73h, 033031DE5h 
                dd 0AA0A4C5Fh, 0DD0D7CC9h, 05005713Ch, 0270241AAh, 0BE0B1010h, 0C90C2086h, 05768B525h, 0206F85B3h, 0B966D409h, 0CE61E49Fh
                dd 05EDEF90Eh, 029D9C998h, 0B0D09822h, 0C7D7A8B4h, 059B33D17h, 02EB40D81h, 0B7BD5C3Bh, 0C0BA6CADh, 0EDB88320h, 09ABFB3B6h
                dd 003B6E20Ch, 074B1D29Ah, 0EAD54739h, 09DD277AFh, 004DB2615h, 073DC1683h, 0E3630B12h, 094643B84h, 00D6D6A3Eh, 07A6A5AA8h 
                dd 0E40ECF0Bh, 09309FF9Dh, 00A00AE27h, 07D079EB1h, 0F00F9344h, 08708A3D2h, 01E01F268h, 06906C2FEh, 0F762575Dh, 0806567CBh
                dd 0196C3671h, 06E6B06E7h, 0FED41B76h, 089D32BE0h, 010DA7A5Ah, 067DD4ACCh, 0F9B9DF6Fh, 08EBEEFF9h, 017B7BE43h, 060B08ED5h
                dd 0D6D6A3E8h, 0A1D1937Eh, 038D8C2C4h, 04FDFF252h, 0D1BB67F1h, 0A6BC5767h, 03FB506DDh, 048B2364Bh, 0D80D2BDAh, 0AF0A1B4Ch
                dd 036034AF6h, 041047A60h, 0DF60EFC3h, 0A867DF55h, 0316E8EEFh, 04669BE79h, 0CB61B38Ch, 0BC66831Ah, 0256FD2A0h, 05268E236h
                dd 0CC0C7795h, 0BB0B4703h, 0220216B9h, 05505262Fh, 0C5BA3BBEh, 0B2BD0B28h, 02BB45A92h, 05CB36A04h, 0C2D7FFA7h, 0B5D0CF31h
                dd 02CD99E8Bh, 05BDEAE1Dh, 09B64C2B0h, 0EC63F226h, 0756AA39Ch, 0026D930Ah, 09C0906A9h, 0EB0E363Fh, 072076785h, 005005713h
                dd 095BF4A82h, 0E2B87A14h, 07BB12BAEh, 00CB61B38h, 092D28E9Bh, 0E5D5BE0Dh, 07CDCEFB7h, 00BDBDF21h, 086D3D2D4h, 0F1D4E242h 
                dd 068DDB3F8h, 01FDA836Eh, 081BE16CDh, 0F6B9265Bh, 06FB077E1h, 018B74777h, 088085AE6h, 0FF0F6A70h, 066063BCAh, 011010B5Ch
                dd 08F659EFFh, 0F862AE69h, 0616BFFD3h, 0166CCF45h, 0A00AE278h, 0D70DD2EEh, 04E048354h, 03903B3C2h, 0A7672661h, 0D06016F7h
                dd 04969474Dh, 03E6E77DBh, 0AED16A4Ah, 0D9D65ADCh, 040DF0B66h, 037D83BF0h, 0A9BCAE53h, 0DEBB9EC5h, 047B2CF7Fh, 030B5FFE9h
                dd 0BDBDF21Ch, 0CABAC28Ah, 053B39330h, 024B4A3A6h, 0BAD03605h, 0CDD70693h, 054DE5729h, 023D967BFh, 0B3667A2Eh, 0C4614AB8h
                dd 05D681B02h, 02A6F2B94h, 0B40BBE37h, 0C30C8EA1h, 05A05DF1Bh, 02D02EF8Dh   
    end
```

While bulding, I'm getting those three errors:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication5, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  Assembling C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm...
    1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(7): error A2206: missing operator in expression
    1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(12): error A2006: undefined symbol : file
    1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(15): error A2081: missing operand after unary operator
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(49,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\crc32.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm"" exited with code 1.
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'll be very greatful for any hint that can helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size` is a reserved word in MASM assembly, so you'll have to come up with a different name for your parameter.

You're also missing a `CRC32 ENDP` after the `ret`.

And you might have to change the function declaration in your C file to `extern unsigned long __stdcall CRC32(size_t *bufLen,  FILE *file);`

---

By the looks of it, your CRC32 function is using its arguments in an incorrect manner. The size argument is a pointer to the size, but you're using it as if it was the size itself. 
And it seems like you try to read from a `FILE*` as if was a pointer to the data in the file, but I'm pretty sure a `FILE*` is just a pointer to a struct containing information about an opened file. To access the data in the file you should use `fread` to read chunks of data into a buffer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've added __stdcall to call, CRC32 endp right before 'end' in Asm code  and I've changed size to sizeOfFile. Still I'm getting those errors + one about 'endp': 1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(59): error A2008: syntax error : endp
1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(7): error A2206: missing operator in expression
1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(12): error A2006: undefined symbol : file
1>C:\Users\sliwkacz\Desktop\New folder\crc32.asm(15): error A2006: undefined symbol : sizeOfFile

Comment: It doesn't seem like you changed the name `size` in all places.

Comment: you can see that the word 'size' itself isn't listed among the errors - i've changed it everywhere

Comment: Could you update your question with your latest code? (exactly the way it is; i.e. copy-pasted from the file you're trying to compile)

Comment: That updated code assembles just fine for me, using MASM 6.14.8444.

Comment: the thing is that I have to compile it in visual studio - my task is to create .dll file from C code which uses asm procedure (sick, i know) but before creating the dll file i would like to run this as the console app just to be sure that it works well

Comment: Visual Studio is just an IDE though. You can tell it which exact assembler to use and which options it should give to the assembler. (I don't remember where you configure this, but I'm sure you could find out by googling)

Comment: I've changed .686 and .387 in asm code to .586. Now I can see linker ONLY errors:1>Source.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000015) "unsigned long __stdcall CRC32(unsigned int,struct _iobuf *)" (?CRC32@@$$FYGKIPAU_iobuf@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl calculateChecksum(char *,char *)" (?calculateChecksum@@$$FYAXPAD0@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __stdcall CRC32(unsigned int,struct _iobuf *)" (?CRC32@@$$FYGKIPAU_iobuf@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl calculateChecksum(char *,char *)" (?calculateChecksum@@$$FYAXPAD0@Z)

Comment: I've added extern "C" before asm function declaration and know it builds! however, the result is a bit wrong... instead of the checksum, I see some kind of strange characters. I bet that now it's a code's fault. I'll be thankful for any help what's wrong in my code

Comment: I pointed out some functional problems in the second part of my answer.

Comment: I've updated the code in my post (just have copied from visual studio) - it doesn't work this way either.